# Is there anything like VisualAssistX for Eclipse? or I'd like some autocomplete with my cup of Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, visual-assist

I'm currently being forced to work with Eclipse on one of my current projects. The language we're working with is C++.

The one thing I miss the most from Visual Studio is VisualAssistX, mostly for its Auto Complete.

Is there anything like it for Eclipse? Or is there anyway to buff Eclipse's autocompletion?

Thanks a lot, people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) provides auto complete and many more features. The auto-complete in particular is not as robust as VisualAssistX, but it still does a great job.